# Pandas inner product of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
df={'x1':[1,2,3,4],
    'x2':[5,6,7,8],
    'y1':[1,2,1,1],
    'y2':[1,1,1,1],
    }
df=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

it looks like

```
  x1 x2 y1 y2
   1  5  1  1
   2  6  2  1
   3  7  1  1
   4  8  1  1
```

how do I get a new column in df x1*y1+x2*y2 as "inner product" ?
first attempt is

```
df['inner']=(df[['x1','x2']*df[['y1','y2']]).sum(axis=1)
```

but failed

should be easy but somehow cannot find any easy answer

Comment: I'm a little confused, you mention "inner product" (or dot product) which would produce a 2x2, but you want to put into a column 4x1?  You might want to clarify that and/or show desired results.  I suspect this has nothing to do with an inner product but your mention of that is confusing as it has a very specific definition for how you multiply 2 matrices.

Answer (score 3):

You could use @EdChum solution for your example. More general:

```
X = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('x')]
Y = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('y')]

df['inner'] = (X.values * Y.values).sum(axis=1)

In [24]: df
Out[24]:
   x1  x2  y1  y2  inner
0   1   5   1   1      6
1   2   6   2   1     10
2   3   7   1   1     10
3   4   8   1   1     12
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be this:

```
In [5]:
df['inner']=(df['x1'] * df['y1']) + (df['x2']*df['y2'])
df

Out[5]:
   x1  x2  y1  y2  inner
0   1   5   1   1      6
1   2   6   2   1     10
2   3   7   1   1     10
3   4   8   1   1     12
```